# What to do when we had a backlink (from a gone site) to one of our a 404 page?

Tags: backlinks, 404

Previously there was a page on our partner's site that had a link to our site. Now, this page and the whole partner's website is gone (404).

But this page still exists in our website backlink profile. Do we need to disavow or take any other action regarding this partner's website (page)?

Answer (score 2):

If the partner's site is gone, the link won't be followed by search engines anymore. So, you can do nothing and wait the backlink disappears from your backlinks profile.